# Auto-start Windows service using C++

Tags: c++, windows

I've been looking into a few tutorials on how to create a Windows service using C++ (unmanaged code).

However, none mention how to register the service for auto-start on Windows boot.

I'm aware of the different security contexts of Windows services.

What mechanism in C++ make the service register for automatic startup?

Comment: It's one of the arguments to CreateService.  Or if you don't control the call to CreateService, you can use ChangeServiceConfig.

Comment: Thanks @HarryJohnston - Could you be a bit more specific regarding the argument?

Comment: Just look at the documentation!  `dwStartType: the service start options`.